# Can't access a wpf control from an outside class

Tags: wpf, class, xaml

I want to call a label control on my main window from an outside class. But the class doesn't recognize it.

My file structure is like this

```
ZoomBorder.cs
MainWindow.xaml
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="GUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PanAndZoom"
        Title="PanAndZoom" Height="600" Width="900" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:ZoomBorder x:Name="border" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Gray">
            <!--<Image Source="/GUI;component/Images/Desert.jpg"/>-->
            <Canvas Width="300" Height="300" Background="Green"></Canvas>
        </local:ZoomBorder>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Label x:Name="pos" x:FieldModifier="public">Position</Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ZoomBorder.cs:**

```
public class ZoomBorder : Border
{
   ...
   private void SomeMethod()
   {
       // this doesn't work!
       pos.Content = "This label is changed by ZoomBorder!";
   }
}
```

Comment: in what way that doesn't work? any exception?

Comment: Yes it throws this error: The name 'pos' does not exist in the current context

Comment: did you tested this.Content ?

Comment: Any reason you're not following the MVVM pattern? WPF is all about MVVM (Model View ViewModel) ;)

Comment: @AndrewMack I know MVVM is the right way to do this, but I guess it is for experienced programmers, right?

Comment: I see it more as just a different way to do things - another tool in your toolbelt. You can saw your way through a thick cedar tree using a handsaw, but if you take a bit of time to learn how to use a chainsaw you'll get the job done that much faster and easier.

Comment: sure, it has a steep learning curve but the benefits are infinite. Any solution for this that doesn't require MVVM for now?

Comment: @franssu I want to change the Label from ZoomBorder class, then how can I do that?  Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Your class ZoomBorder has no real reference to your label control. Sure, you wrote out `pan.Content="New Text";` but how does your class know who/what/where "pan" is?

I'd take a look at csteinmueller's answer. Looks like you will get the reference to the label using the code he gave you there.

Comment: @AndrewMack I checked his code, didn't work either. How can I do this the MVVM way?

Comment: @Vahid Yes, your are missing something obvious : sibling fields of an instance don't have any reference on each other. There are many ways of doing what you want to do, all of them implying something to happen at the parent level i.e. MainWindow.cs

Comment: @franssu After two days I got what you meant :D thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason for it to work. What you're trying to do is pretty much equivalent to :

```
class Parent // = MainWindow
{
   object xxx;
   Child child;
}

class Child // = ZoomBorder
{
   void SomeFunction()
   {
       this.xxx = ...; // Doesn't work, the class Child doesn't have any xxx field
   }
}
```

Comment: I thought if I define a control public, I will be able to access it from the outside class. I'm totally lost :(

Comment: What do you mean by "defining a control public" ?

Comment: <Label x:Name="pos" x:FieldModifier="public">Position</Label>

Comment: The ZoomBorder and Label you declared are both instance variables of the MainWindow class. They don't have any knowledge of each other's existence. If you want something happening on the ZoomBorder to trigger something on the Label, you'll have to add code at the MainWindow level..

Answer (score 1):

The way you tried is only works if the property defined in the same class :

```
pos.Content = "This label is changed by ZoomBorder!";
```

In case of static property from other class, you can access it this way :

```
MainWindow.pos = ....
//or generally
ClassName.PropertyName = ....
```

Unfortunately UI controls in your XAML isn't static property. In case of non static property from other class, you need class instance to access the property :

```
MainWindow mainWindowInstance = new MainWindow();
mainWindowInstance.pos = ....
```

Snippet above is only example, in your case you'll need to find a way to pass current `MainWindow` instance displayed to `ZoomBorder` instead of creating new instance as this example demonstrates.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var wnd = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
var label = wnd.pos;
```